# Expected Waiting Time (Poisson Distribution)

Tags: probability

I am doing the following question and have done the first three parts. I am stuck on the last part.

[image]

I took a look at the hints for this question and it says that:

[image]

I am not sure how it gets the $\frac{1}{\lambda + \mu}$? Can anybody explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From part (i), the number of fish caught by both people is also Poisson with parameter $\lambda + \mu$. Using the fact given in (iv), this implies the waiting time until the first caught fish (regardless of who caught it) is $\frac{1}{\lambda + \mu}$.